# cross-origin request works from localhost but not from server

Tags: javascript, cors

I am trying to request some json resources from google apis (picasa photos) from my JS. Can someone explain why my request would succeed when my site is served as localhost on my mac, but not from my development server (using chrome browser)?

Comment: Are you getting any specific errors when you try and make the request from the server?

Comment: This is the url I'm trying to "GET" from my jquery ajax call: http://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/112919777333345923386?alt=json

When requesting it from my site via dev server (a linux apache server at my house), I see the request method as "OPTIONS" and the status says "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

When requesting it with the site served from my mac (site.localhost, also apache), it works fine.

This tells me it's not really a problem with cross-origin. Also, the above happens with Chrome browser. Firefox always succeeds.

Comment: What `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is returned when accessed from your dev server?

Comment: I'm not sure why, but this seemed to be some kind of caching issue. I cleared all history/cache settings in chrome and now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This happens due to cross domain, cross browser request issues. JSONP may help. [Take a look at this example](http://codeforbrowser.com/blog/cross-domain-request-with-jquery-and-jsonp/)

Answer (score 0):

Cors must be supported and enabled on server side beside the browser compatibity.